# Random material on realized instances

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes

I have created wall from wooden planks as a simple geo nodes instances on grid. I wanted them to have slightly different shade, so I did with Color ramp factored by object info. However when I tried to make windows with boolen meshes, my modifier did not worked, until i put „realize instances” node by the end of my node chain. It worked for boolen, nevertheless it made somehow one object from many instances so blender do not randomize shaders any longer. Is there some way to randomize them anyhow?

Comment: You can only color instances differently if you apply the `Realize Instances` node. Also, there are many questions on this topic here on BSE ([search results](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgeometry-nodes%5D+instance+color)). Furthermore, your question is hard to answer in this state anyway if you don't know the node tree. Please be so kind and try to explain this in more detail or clarify it with a screenshot of your nodes. To answer your question it might also be helpful if you share your blend file with us: https://blend-exchange.com/